# Making sure NODE_OPTIONS --max-old-space-size is working

Tags: node.js, memory, memory-management

This may sound weird but I am setting `--max-old-space-size` option and I want to make sure that the configuration is in place so that I dont get runtime errors.

Is there a way to verify memory limit during runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to verify how much memory you are actually using you can call

```
process.memoryUsage()
```

which will return

```
{
  rss: 4935680,
  heapTotal: 1826816,
  heapUsed: 650472,
  external: 49879
}
```

heapTotal refers to memory available.  heapUsed referred to heap memory used and external refers to the memory usage of C++ objects bound to JavaScript objects managed by V8. rss, Resident Set Size, is the amount of space occupied in the main memory device
https://nodejs.org/api/process.html

Comment: So which of these 4 numbers is the one limited by the `--max-old-space-size`? I used to think it was `rss`, but now I have `"rss":409.92` despite setting `--max_old_space_size=350`. Having an explicit answer to the OP's question would help a lot...

Comment: process.memoryUsage() returns same with various --max-old-space-size on my x64 Debian. So that is not the answer. Pls see my answer below.

Answer (score 15):

To get heap size in megabytes pls use

```
const v8 = require('v8')
v8.getHeapStatistics().total_available_size / 1024 / 1024
```

Example 1

> node --max-old-space-size=256
>
> v8.getHeapStatistics().total_available_size / 1024 / 1024
>
> 284.47106170654297

Example 2

> node --max-old-space-size=512
>
> v8.getHeapStatistics().total_available_size / 1024 / 1024
>
> 544.9713745117188

Example 3

> export NODE_OPTIONS=--max-old-space-size=1024
>
> node
>
> v8.getHeapStatistics().total_available_size / 1024 / 1024
>
> 1065.4709014892578

So, as we can see, both command line arg and env variable NODE_OPTIONS work.